# async and await in angular api response

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to do task step by step.

I have a for loop in a method:

```
async changeTimeStep3() {
  for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    await this.do(i)
  }
}
```

for each step must do() task.

```
do(i) {
  this.http
    .getDataFromServer(
      "api/example?id=" +i
    )
    .subscribe((response) => {
     console.log(i);
    });
}
```

I want to wait to get response and after response coming go to next `i`

But not work console.log print:

```
2
3
5
1
4
7
8
9
6
```

Note time to receive response from api is not fix.

Any help?

Comment: do doesn't return a promise to await...

Comment: why? and how to do in right way? @jonrsharpe

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't return a promise, you presumably wrote it like that, or why you're awaiting it even though it doesn't. And if you want to await it, try actually returning a promise that resolves when the work is done (or rejects if it fails).

Comment: I realize that this doesn't answer your question, but making calls like that is an anti-pattern. If you need to await multiple calls in a loop, you need to pass a collection to the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return a `Promise` and use `resolve()` in response part of your ajax. Like:

```
do(i) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.http.getDataFromServer("api/example?id=" +i).subscribe((response) => {
      resolve(response);
    }, (error) => {
      console.error(error);
      reject();
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: I was editing. yes it is parallel. I put the sequential model too. @jonrsharpe

Comment: loops in `for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {}` are different from `for (const i of arr) {}` model. @jonrsharpe

Comment: and just now I came up with a better answer...

Comment: You are right. My apologies. I will update the answer to the right solution.

Comment: Now it's just https://stackoverflow.com/a/70335844/3001761, with the [same problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70335718/async-and-await-in-angular-api-response/70335856#comment124332649_70335844).

Comment: No that answer didn't do `resolve(response)`.

Comment: `.method((value) => func(value))`, absent any `this`-binding problems, is the same as `.method(func)`.

Comment: well what is the problem with both of our answers? I did something like this in my project and it worked. @jonrsharpe

Comment: work like a sharme, thank you !!

Comment: And here is the problem with letting the OP decide the best answer. As I said in the linked comment from the first time someone posted this answer, it doesn't handle errors and _you almost never need to new up a Promise_.

Comment: @jackros we can't see the details of `getDataFromServer` (it's not a standard [`HttpClient` method](https://angular.io/guide/http)), but if there are _any_ circumstances in which the observable it returns emits an _error_ (e.g. non-2xx response status codes or outright request failures are commonly represented this way) that will **not** get propagated if you use this technique. That's why RxJS includes [appropriate methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70335893/3001761), so that all states are handled correctly.

Comment: This clumsy `new Promise` wrapping an Observable really isn't the way to go. I don't know why OP marked it as accepted. @Batajus's answer above is far better.

Answer (score 8):

To get your loop print out the values in the correct order you could transform your observables into promises, so your `await` will block the `for`-loop as long as the HTTP call hasn't resolved.

```
import { firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

...

async do(i: number) {
  await firstValueFrom(
    this.http
      .getDataFromServer(
        "api/example?id=" +i
      )
  );
  console.log(i);
}
```

Using `firstValueFrom` or `lastValueFrom` are the RxJS ways to get a promise as return value from an observable (since `toPromise` got deprecated, you can read more about that [here](https://indepth.dev/posts/1287/rxjs-heads-up-topromise-is-being-deprecated)).

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that do is not an asynchronous method; it is a synchronous method that triggers an asynchronous one.  As such, the await completes immediately.

You may be able to do this:

```
do(i) {
  return firstValueFrom(this.http
    .getDataFromServer(
      "api/example?id=" +i
    ))
}
```

It converts the observable into a promise and returns it.  So, now the do() method returns an async object.  To output from the do method; you can use a pipe:

```
  return firstValueFrom(this.http
    .getDataFromServer(
      "api/example?id=" +i
    ).pipe(tap((result) => {console.log(i);}))
```

All that said, using async/await in Angular is unusual.  An RXJS operator is usually considered the right approach. Possibly with [concat](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/concat)

Comment: Subscribing returns a subscription, not a promise - that has the same problem the OP currently does.

Comment: I think this has a completely different problem, but good call on the promise/subscribe issue.

Comment: It has the same problem insofar as you're awaiting something that's not a promise, therefore awaiting it is pointless because it doesn't synchronise the behaviour.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I edited the answer; so it should be more accurate now.